# Find a basis for the subspace and state the dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

${\{(a, b, c) : a-3b=0, b-2c=0, 2b-c=0}\}$

The answer states that there is no basis and that the dimension is 0, however I am unsure why. I suspect it is to do with all the equations equalling zero but this doesn't really help. Can someone explain why this is the case? Thanks.

Comment: What is the only triple that satisfies all of the equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what the requirements force on $a,b,c$: $b = 2c$ but $c = 2b$ as well, so $b = 4b$. This means $b = 0$. What can you now say about $a$ and $c$?